# Reading .sav file into R

Tags: r, spss

I am trying to read a .sav file into R but I got the following warning:

```
library("memisc")
dataset <- data.frame(as.data.set(spss.system.file("dataset.sav")))
```

> parseSysHeader(ptr) :  file lacks info_flt64 record, using defaults

Could someone tell me what this warning means and how to fix it?
Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Takahiro

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You can also use the ['haven' package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/haven/haven.pdf) to read in the SPSS file.  This package has much more consistency over the foreign package, with regard to syntax.  Also, the resulting data frame will have both the 'tbl_df' and 'tbl' classes so printing will be improved if dplyr is loaded.

```
library(haven)

path = file.path("C:/", "Folder", "dataset.sav")
dataset = read_sav(path)
```

Comment: You can try this code too. So you can do it effortlessly without typing path. 
  `dataset=read_sav(file.choose())`

Answer (score 25):

You can use the library `foreign` to import data from `.sav` (SPSS) format.

```
library(foreign)

data <- read.spss("C:/PathToFile/dataset.sav", to.data.frame=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 6):

Another option could be my R package [`readspss`](https://github.com/JanMarvin/readspss). The syntax is similar to the one of the `foreign` package. The imported data is returned as a `data.frame()` with attributes. The package was written from scratch and features read and write support for all SPSS files (zsav, sav and por). It was tested with a variety of SPSS files and supports reading of (hopefully) all SPSS features (e.g. encrypted and or compressed files, long strings, and all types of missings).

```
library(readspss)
dataset <- read.sav("dataset.sav")
```